# FFmpeg development on Eclipse on Windows

Tags: c++, eclipse, ffmpeg, mingw, cross-compiling

The first thing I did was to refer to [tutorial](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/Setup_Eclipse_IDE_for_FFmpeg_%28Linux%29) on FFmpeg site.

I set up MSYS+MinGW64, I cloned all the relevant pre-requisites (i.e OpenSSL, x264, rtmpdump),
I successfully cross-compiled them all. I ran the configure for FFmpeg, and I was able to cross-compile that as well. And my statically linked ffmpeg.exe works to my satisfaction.

In Eclipse I was able to create a project, load up the source code, navigate it, make some changes, even compile and step-through debug. The problem I am having is with the Eclipse design-time error, and I think this is more of an Eclipse/C++ thing than FFmpeg.

For example in ffmpeg.c I find this error "Field 'bitstream_filters' could not be resolved" at this line:

```
AVBitStreamFilterContext *bsfc = output_streams[i]->bitstream_filters;
```

that `output_streams` is of type

```
OutputStream **output_streams
```

and when I try to open the declaration for `OutputStream` Eclipse gives me the option of two locations. Obviously Eclipse is not sure which of these declarations it is, hence the "could not be resolved" error. `OutputStream` is defined in the following 2 files

- ffmpeg.h
- libavformat/smoothstreamingenc.c

(hmm nice to know FFmpeg can do smooth streaming...) but anyway the correct definition would of been the one in ffmpeg.h.

So... the whole goal of getting the source into an IDE was so that I could enjoy the benefits of such things like intelisense. What can I do in Eclipse to set some sort of order or rule as to how it should resolve types in cases where the names clash like this?

Comment: I need your help about set up of ffmpeg with eclipse. Actually I stuck at when run command "sudo chomd +x build_android.sh". I am running this command on cygwin. I skip this command and run another command "./build_android.sh" to execute this script file. But now getting other errors. I found approx all the tutorial which developed their code on linux. Actually somewhere I read that on windows this script file gives many error. Please help me or give a tutorial which works for Windows. Thanks

Comment: Sorry I'm not even sure the context of your trouble. You mention the build_android.sh script. But where is this coming from? You are trying to build ffmpeg for android?